# How to render this array into usable json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

So i have this coming back from my webscrape

```
formatted_total_price
&Acirc;&pound;66.00
formatted_total_price
&Acirc;&pound;128.00
formatted_total_price
&Acirc;&pound;246.00
formatted_total_price
&Acirc;&pound;243.20
formatted_total_price
&Acirc;&pound;242.86
formatted_total_price
&Acirc;&pound;242.50
```

Heres the code for this:

```
   if text.content =~ /more_options_on_polling/
     price1 = text.to_s.scan(/\"(formatted_(?:total_price))\":\"(.+?)\"/).uniq
     puts price1
   end
```

How would i go about making this into json so that i can append just the price to a table?

Thanks
Sam

Comment: 1 question is enough. You didn't duplicate the same question, but 4 times in a row...

Comment: What would you like the json to look like?